# How to maintain code formatting of javascirpt with JSP tags in Netbeans

Tags: javascript, jsp, netbeans

One of the problems I have been running into with using JSP tags in JavaScript files is that it breaks the automatic formatting in netbeans. This is cumbersome as it makes the code hard to read and throws errors in the action items window.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that if you put comment marker before it, JSP will just process things like normal and ignore the //, while the JavaScript treats the line as a comment line and no longer messes up the code:

```
options: [
    //<c:forEach items="${pages}" var="page">
    {label: "${page.value.getName()}", value: ${page.key}},
    //</c:forEach>
],
```